# Python sudoku solver

Tags: python

Trying to create my own sudoku solver.

I'm using 0 as blank

The solver is almost done but sometimes it doesn't replace 0. What's the problem here?

```
def sud(nums):

    for row in nums:
        for n in row:
            if n == 0:
                under = [u_row[row.index(n)] for u_row in sudoku]
                for i in range(1, 10):
                    if i not in row and i not in under:
                        row[row.index(n)] = i

    return nums
```

nums here is a list with sudoku, for example:

```
sudoku = [
[0, 0, 6, 0, 5, 4, 9, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 4, 2],
[7, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 8, 1],
[0, 5, 0, 3, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0],
[4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[9, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 7]
]
```

And this is my output for this list:

```
[2, 3, 6, 8, 5, 4, 9, 1, 7]
[1, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 0, 4, 2]
[7, 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 6, 3, 5]
[3, 7, 6, 2, 9, 5, 4, 8, 1]
[8, 5, 1, 3, 4, 7, 6, 2, 9]
[4, 6, 2, 9, 1, 3, 7, 0, 0]
[5, 3, 4, 6, 2, 7, 1, 9, 8]
[9, 2, 4, 8, 3, 7, 0, 5, 0]
[6, 9, 5, 4, 8, 1, 3, 2, 7]
```

Comment: Why is there a 10 appearing in the code, when in Sudoku almost everything runs up to 9?

Comment: @Jens 10 is not included in the range...the loop runs from 1 to 9

Comment: Are you sure you are giving correct input sudoku? Maybe the input is unsolvable? And one more sidenote... You are not checking if the number exist in one 3X3 block..

Comment: If this is supposed to solve real sudoku, it is way too simplistic. Also I can't follow what your definition and use of `under` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Do you have an example of a set of data that didn't get entirely solved? My guess would be that, since the algorithm might enter wrong data, it can occur that one row has the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 and the crossing column has 6,7,8,9. Meaning that even if there's an empty cell in both the "cross", your algorithm won't fill it because it thinks all the possible numbers already exists in the same row or column.

Comment: @khelwood under is a generated row of a specific column. I'm checking either the number is in the row or in the column

Comment: @vonniklasson I've added output to my topic

Comment: I can see in your output grid that you've added numbers into the grid in such a way that you have made it impossible to complete. If there each number 1-9 is either already in the row or already in the column, then it will stay at zero. Basically your program just guesses at the correct numbers and it guesses wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is flawed. What you are doing is, that you put the first number that is not in the row or column in the position. But this is not always the case. There can be multiple such numbers possible.

For example in your input sudoku, the first element can have 2,3,6 and 8 as its initial value.

What you have to do, is that if the final board still contains zeroes, then backtrack to a previous state and try putting another number, and solve recursively for that state.

Read about [Backtracking here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)